# How to set up pod communication between 2 different Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: kubernetes

I am working on a use case where I need to set up 2 Kubernetes Cluster ,and establish communication channel between 2 pods that are in separate GKE clusters.
Please suggest a solution as how to implement the same.

Comment: As long as they are in the same VPC, they can communicate via internal IPs, but I don't know of DNS based solutions.

Comment: this is way too broad of a question. there are hundereds of ways to establish communication between two entities and pods are no different. you may want to check out message queues (there are lots of them as well), rest, grpc etc. too many ways to fit in one post or article.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these steps in kubernetes cluster

First cluster

```
1. Create deployment.
2.Expose Deployment using service type as NodePort.
3. Enable firewall rule for Port that is exposed by service.
4. List out node IP address.
```

Second cluster

```
1. Create deployment 
2. In deployment you can point endpoint of first cluster service 
as a environment vriables
        env:
        - name: SERVICE_URL
          value: xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxxx
```

Here xx.xx.xx.xx will be your clusters node IP and xxxx will be your cluster Node Port.

Like this your 1st cluster pod will communicate with 2nd cluster pod

Comment: If clusters are in Same VPC you dont need external IP to communicate. Internal IP's will be enough. But lets say, it is outside of VPC you need external IP to communicate with clusters

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [Istio](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/multicluster-deployments/).

Here is a detailed [guide](https://istio.io/docs/examples/multicluster/gke/) of how to:

> configure a multicluster mesh with a single-network shared control
>   plane topology over 2 Google Kubernetes Engine clusters.

This would allow inter-cluster direct pod-to-pod communication.

Please let me know if that helped.